# RabbitMQ AMQP protocol mismatch

Tags: rabbitmq

```
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost(host);
    Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
```

> ```
> com.rabbitmq.client.MalformedFrameException: AMQP protocol version mismatch; we are version 0-9-1, server sent signature 1,1,0,10
> ```

When I try and create a new RabbitMQ connection I am getting this error. Weirdly I installed the RabbitMQ 2.8.2 server on two different linux boxes and one works and the other one doesnt.
Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem specific to a single session on one machine, which has since been rebooted and so is no longer applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Does one of the boxes have Apache QPID running on it? That'd explain your version mismatch. RabbitMQ Server currently only goes as far as 0.9.1.